# Polymorphic query for tags on multiple objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I have an `Author` model that `has_many :posts`, `has_many :comments` it also can be `taggable` based on the `Tagging` and `Tag` models that I've posted below.

```rb
class Tagging
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :taggable, polymorphic: true
end
```

```rb
class Tag
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :posts, through: :taggings, source: :taggable, source_type: 'Post'
  has_many :authors, through: :taggings, source: :taggable, source_type: 'Author'
end
```

Here's what my `Author` model looks like.

```
class Author
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments
  has_many :taggings, as: :taggable
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings
end
```

There are a few types of queries that I'm attempted but all of my attempts throw errors, and I can't wrap my head around how to get to the data I want.  Basically I'd like to run queries for the following scenarios:

- Let's say I have an author object `@author = Author.find(1)`.  How would I go about getting all related comments and posts grouped by tags that the author has created?  I'm not sure how to build this AR object.
- How would I find all comments and posts by an author that share a specific tag?  For this I've tried `@taggable = @author.tagging.joins(:tag).where(tags: {name: @tag_name})`, but I can't do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the gem [acts_as_taggable](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on),then its easy to find taggable records using [tagged_with](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/blob/master/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/taggable/core.rb) utility.

```
##get the author
@author = Author.find params[:id]
##get the authors category/tags
cat = @author.tags
##find all post/comments that are tagged with cat
Author.includes(:post, :comments, :tags).tagged_with(cat,:any=>true)}.flatten.compact.uniq
```

IF,you are not using acts_as_taggable :(,then you have to construct your own query...which can be like this..

```
Author.includes(:post, :comments, :tags).where(tags: {taggable_type: 'Author',taggable_id: @author.id}).flatten.compact.uniq
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  Unfortunately I'm not using acts_as_taggable and I'm using the custom classes I defined above.  I was hoping to avoid using that gem for learning purposes.  Any ideas how to do these queries without the gem?

Comment: Well..there are reasons why gems are made...to easy our life because someone has already done that effort that you are doing it again.... :).You need to make a sql query using taggable_type/id to check ...